# How can I get the Icon to be clickable and let it allow changing the value inside Input?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I have `Input` container in which a name exists. The functionality is that the name can be renamed. But I want it in such a way that whenever user clicks on `CreateIcon` (which is inside InputAdornment) the name is changeable. Only when I click around the text, I'm able to change it.

Here's the [code](https://codesandbox.io/live/04f4e253f91) 
[image]

```
const [name, setName] = useState('Neha')
  const [nameTemp, setNameTemp] = useState('Neha')
  const [isHovered, setIsHovered] = useState(false)
  const changingSimualtionName = (val) => {
    setName(val)
    setIsHovered(true)
  }
  const handleSavingName = () =>{
    setIsHovered(false)
    setNameTemp(name)
  }
  const resetName = () =>{
    setIsHovered(false)
    setName(nameTemp)
  }
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <Input
                defaultValue={nameTemp}
                value={name}
                endAdornment={
                  isHovered ? (
                    <div></div>
                  ) : (
                    <InputAdornment position="end">
                      <CreateIcon />
                    </InputAdornment>
                  )
                }
                onChange={(event) => {
                  changingSimualtionName(event.target.value);
                }}
              />
              {isHovered ? (
              <Grid item >
                <IconButton
                  onClick={handleSavingName}
                >
                  <CheckCircle />
                </IconButton>
                <IconButton
                  data-test-id="btn-cancel-simulation-name"
                  onClick={resetName}
                >
                  <CancelIcon />
                </IconButton>
              </Grid>
            ) : (
              <div></div>
            )}
    </div>
  );
```

**Code Review Suggestion**: Also, is there a way that name doesn't change on every change of the value and only changes when user clicks on `Tick icon`? I tried it with useRef but wasn't able to do it.

Comment: Please add some code that you've tried out. Then it's easy to go from there. And there is nothing in codesandbox link.

Comment: Please add the code, currently your link opens a blank React Project

Comment: For me it is opening up in the link. Trying again.

Answer (score 0):

Umh... try:

```
const [editable, setEditable] = useState(false)

<InputAdornment position="end">
    <CreateIcon onClick={() => setEditable(x=>!x)} />
</InputAdornment>

<Input disabled={!editable} ... />
```

Comment: This only works when I click on the icon. I want the name to be editable when the user clicks anywhere on Input too

Comment: The onClick callback on Input does not work? es: <Input onClick={() => setEditable(true)}